# Access SQL - given two dates, return the dates of the previous period

Tags: sql, ms-access

I need to find the dates of the preceding time period - e.g. if the given months are Jan-13 to Mar-13, I need to be able to calculate that the previous period is Oct-12 to Dec-12. Or if the dates are Jul-12 to Jun-13, I need to come up with Jul-11 to Jun 12. So basically for a time period of x months, I need to return another time period of x months that finishes the month before the specified time period.

The date will always be the first of the month, so 1st June 2012 or 6/1/2012 or 1/6/2012 depending on where you are in the world.

This SQL query works, but seems to be causing problems later on when I incorporate it in a Left Join query (see existing question: [Access 2007 - Left Join to a query returns #Error instead of Null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17170426/access-2007-left-join-to-a-query-returns-error-instead-of-null))

```
SELECT DATEADD("m",
1-(1+MONTH(QueryDates.EndDate)-MONTH(QueryDates.StartDate)+
    (12*(YEAR(QueryDates.EndDate)-YEAR(QueryDates.StartDate)))),
DATEADD("m",-1,QueryDates.StartDate)) AS StartDatePrevious, 
DATEADD("m",-1,QueryDates.StartDate) AS EndDatePrevious
FROM QueryDates;
```

It looks a bit crazy from where I'm sitting, so is there a simpler way of achieving this task; or is there anything wrong in the SQL that could confuse Access later on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How does this work for you? This is, I believe, the same thing you're doing in your query, but using the DateDiff function makes it look less gnarly. DateDiff tells you that (for example) there are 2 months between 1/1/2013 and 3/1/2013. Therefore we are looking at a 3-month span, so we subtract 3 months from both the start date and the end date to get the previous span:

```
SELECT DateAdd("m",DateDiff("m",EndDate,StartDate)-1,StartDate) AS StartDatePrevious
,DateAdd("m",DateDiff("m",EndDate,StartDate)-1,EndDate) AS EndDatePrevious
FROM QueryDates;
```

By the way, unless I'm mistaken, I believe you intended to say "...I need to be able to calculate that the previous period is **Oct-12** to **Dec-12**..."

Comment: Thank you, yes this works. Unfortunately it doesn't solve the #Error problem that I'm getting further along the line, will have to find a way around that, but it should make it easier for someone else to work out what the query is doing when I'm not admin on the database anymore.  :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a little cleaner SQL. It assumes that the StartDate is always the first of the month.

This calculates the period length, and returns the same length ending the day before the current period starts.

```
SELECT QueryDates.StartDate, 
       QueryDates.EndDate, 
       Dateadd("m", Datediff("m", [EndDate] + 1, [StartDate]), [StartDate]) AS 
       StartDatePrevious, 
       [StartDate] - 1                                                      AS 
       EndDatePrevious 
FROM   QueryDates;
```

Comment: I can see how that works, but the dates will always be the first of the month, so I need to use some kind of date function to subtract one month from the StartDate to find the EndDatePrevious.