# Access SQL - Convert Text to Number

Tags: sql, ms-access, left-join

I've had the same problem as described here: [Access 2007 - Left Join to a query returns #Error instead of Null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17170426/access-2007-left-join-to-a-query-returns-error-instead-of-null)

for which, the solution seems to be; write a better calculated field column so that the error doesn't occur later down the line - described here: [Access SQL - given two dates, return the dates of the previous period](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17195928/access-sql-given-two-dates-return-the-dates-of-the-previous-period)

However, my calculated column is really simple, only converting a text field to a number field (e.g. "003" -> "3");

```
 RevisionNumber = CDbl([RevisionText])
```

Further to this, The process works in a left join further up the chain?!

I changed the calculated field to a constant as detailed in the comments on the answer. But this gave me a new error

> "Each GROUP BY expression must contain at least one column that is not an outer reference"

Here's the comment:

> In my test example, if I switched the calculated field for a constant (e.g. 3 or "Test") then this value did indeed appear for every chain, whether they appeared in the right hand side of the join or not. For a calculated field it returned an error. Only when it was a direct reference to a single field did it work properly. If I do solve it I'll post the workaround here. –  Wilskt

So it must be in my SQL code??

```
SELECT QryDATATRIncompleteRequired.*,_
QryDATATRLatestCompleted.LevelTrained, CDbl([RevisionTrained]) AS [Revision Trained], _
QryDATATRLatestCompleted.TrainerSignOff, QryDATATRLatestCompleted.DateAwarded, _
QryDATATRLatestCompleted.ValidTo_
FROM QryDATATRIncompleteRequired LEFT JOIN QryDATATRLatestCompleted ON _
(QryDATATRIncompleteRequired.EmployeeID = QryDATATRLatestCompleted.EmployeeID) _
AND (QryDATATRIncompleteRequired.SubjectTitle = QryDATATRLatestCompleted.Subject);
```

Comment: where is your query statement? There is no group by in your code?

Comment: This SQL Code calls on a number of sub queries (nested queries?). QryOXISTRIncompleteRequired relies on QryOXISTRIncomplete and QryOXISTRRequired, which themselves rely on other queries. These have groups in them. Which GROUP BY is causing the error might be difficult to find. Presumably by trawling through all the queries?