# Access - Left Join returns #Error instead of Null

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, left-join, calculated-field

I've asked a similar question already, but I've now simplified the tables/queries enough to put up an example database with (hopefully) descriptive naming:

https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B2PZcGkhNyd4THpWa01fTjVvSWM/edit?usp=sharing

There is one query, ChainsCasesPerMonthPerStorePreviousMonthRange, which works fine. It takes data from two tables and the QueryDatesPrevious query, to return data for the previous period to the one specified in the QueryDates table. Everything seems okay up to this stage.

But when I run the query LeftJoinReturnsError, the three extra chains in the Chains table return #Error instead of returning the expected Null.

If I change QueryDatesPrevious from a query to a table everything works fine, so this seems to be where the problem lies, but I can't seem to solve it, even using an Iif(IsNull, Null, 0) condition.

An extra 50 rep points to the person who solves it, as long as I can work out how to transfer them across.  :)

(previous question if you're interested: [Access 2007 - Left Join to a query returns #Error instead of Null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17170426/access-2007-left-join-to-a-query-returns-error-instead-of-null))

-- EDIT UPDATE --

Output would look something like this, although I don't remember the exact data I put in the test database:

```
Chain                 CasesPerMonthPerStore
AgriStore             2.33
Agricultural Export   
2B Pencils            3.6
Bob's Markets
```

So basically, any chain in the Chain table that isn't in the other tables should return Null as part of the left join.

Comment: To transfer the rep, set a bounty on the question. You should have enough rep. I'll take a look at your doc.

Comment: I looked at it, and I know what the problem is. I'm away from a Windows machine right now so I can't double check everything. As soon as I get back, I'll post a detailed answer.

Comment: You big tease Brian. :) It's eligible for bounty in 17 hours, so I'll do this Sunday and you could post up your answer after that. I'm curious to see what your ideas are as I've wasted a day and a half on this so far! Cheers,

Comment: I looked at it again and I'm not so sure I know the answer. I do have one more question: what should the output look like? There's different ways to approach the problem.

Comment: Not sure it's 100% correct on the data, but I've edited the question to include the result I'm looking for. I'm wondering whether it's caused by this bug, and how I could work around it... http://allenbrowne.com/BugOuterJoinExpression.html

Comment: I can offset your rep loss a little too. This is actually a great question. It's exactly the kind of thing Access users need to know about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so I set up another query that just returns the chains that should return a Null value for CasesPerMonthPerStore, but are actually returning #Error in my test database:

```
SELECT Chains.Chain
FROM Chains LEFT JOIN ChainsNumStoresPreviousMonthRange ON Chains.Chain = ChainsNumStoresPreviousMonthRange.Chain
WHERE ChainsNumStoresPreviousMonthRange.NumberOfStores Is Null;
```

So in my written example in the question above this query would return:

```
Chain
Agricultural Export
Bob's Markets
```

I then UNION these chains, along with a Null field, to the query that returns all of the chains that do return a value for CasesPerMonthPerStore:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT ChainsCasesPerMonthPerStorePreviousMonthRange.Chain, ChainsCasesPerMonthPerStorePreviousMonthRange.CasesPerMonthPerStore
FROM ChainsCasesPerMonthPerStorePreviousMonthRange
UNION ALL
SELECT ChainsNotInPreviousPeriod.Chain, NULL
FROM ChainsNotInPreviousPeriod)  AS UnionQuery
ORDER BY Chain;
```

So the secret seems to be to separate the calculated field away from the left join. It's the first time I've come across this error, and I don't know whether this approach would work in every situation, but it worked for me.  :)

Thanks for your time Brian & Gord,

Answer (score 2):

This is rather ugly too, but it seems to work:

Run the following query to create a table named [tblChainsCasesPerMonthPerStorePreviousMonthRange]:

```
SELECT ChainsCasesPerMonthPerStorePreviousMonthRange.* 
INTO tblChainsCasesPerMonthPerStorePreviousMonthRange
FROM ChainsCasesPerMonthPerStorePreviousMonthRange;
```

Create a query named [updChainsCasesPerMonthPerStorePreviousMonthRange] as an Update query that saves the results of [ChainsCasesPerMonthPerStorePreviousMonthRange] into [tblChainsCasesPerMonthPerStorePreviousMonthRange]:

```
INSERT INTO tblChainsCasesPerMonthPerStorePreviousMonthRange
SELECT ChainsCasesPerMonthPerStorePreviousMonthRange.*
FROM ChainsCasesPerMonthPerStorePreviousMonthRange;
```

Paste the following Function into a standard VBA Module

```
Public Function RemakeTable() As Variant
Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef
Debug.Print "Executing RemakeTable()..."
CurrentDb.Execute "DELETE FROM tblChainsCasesPerMonthPerStorePreviousMonthRange", dbFailOnError
Set qdf = CurrentDb.QueryDefs("updChainsCasesPerMonthPerStorePreviousMonthRange")
qdf.Execute
Set qdf = Nothing
RemakeTable = Null
End Function
```

Update your [LeftJoinReturnsError] query to

```
SELECT 
    Chains.Chain, 
    tblChainsCasesPerMonthPerStorePreviousMonthRange.CasesPerMonthPerStore,
    RemakeTable() AS Junk
FROM 
    Chains 
    LEFT JOIN 
    tblChainsCasesPerMonthPerStorePreviousMonthRange 
        ON Chains.Chain=tblChainsCasesPerMonthPerStorePreviousMonthRange.Chain;
```

The final query has an extra column named [Junk], but at least we get the desired result.

Note: I put the `Debug.Print` in the VBA Function to verify that it only gets called once, not once for each row in the query.

Comment: I'm not going to try this because I want to keep the database as simple as possible for the next admin, but I can see how it works. Am I right in thinking that when you call the final SELECT statement, with Remaketable() AS Junk in it, it calls the VBA Function which then deletes and updates the contents of the table? If so, I had no idea you could call VBA functions from a standard SELECT query! That opens up lots of new avenues......

Comment: @Wilskt Yes, that's exactly what it does. Queries executed from within Access itself can include user-defined functions written in VBA. I tried several different variations of using a VBA function before posting that one because the idea of relying on a side-effect of the `RemakeTable()` function was not too appealing, but **(1)** it does seem to work, **(2)** it still uses a "normal" invocation of the final SELECT query (no need to remember to run a separate query first), and **(3)** sometimes when working around a bug "you gotta do what you gotta do...".

Answer (score 1):

Great post on the bug. I hadn't seen that, but it's quite obvious that's exactly what's happening. The only way I can see to deal with it since Access doesn't support lateral joins or SQL Server's APPLY clause, is to elevate the expression to the select clause in the top level query. The following gives you the output you want:

```
SELECT Chains.Chain, (SELECT ChainsCasesPerMonthPerStorePreviousMonthRange.CasesShipped/(DateDiff("m",ChainsCasesPerMonthPerStorePreviousMonthRange.StartDatePrevious,ChainsCasesPerMonthPerStorePreviousMonthRange.EndDatePrevious)+1)/ChainsCasesPerMonthPerStorePreviousMonthRange.NumberOfStores AS Expr1 from ChainsCasesPerMonthPerStorePreviousMonthRange WHERE ChainsCasesPerMonthPerStorePreviousMonthRange.Chain = Chains.Chain) as Expr2
FROM Chains;
```

It's pretty ugly, but it works. Of course in SQL Server or another DB, you wouldn't need lateral joins because the process outer joins with expressions correctly.

Comment: You might want to check your work. When I try to run your query I get prompted for a number of "Parameter" values because there are unrecognized column names: `ChainsCasesPerMonthPerStorePreviousMonthRange.CasesShipped`, `ChainsCasesPerMonthPerStorePreviousMonthRange.StartDatePrevious`, ....

Comment: Think some of the table names were mixed up, but that's not surprisingly looking at how long they are. I got a version of this working and it returned correct results for the test data, but when I scale it up to my working data the query is incredibly slow. I presume it's calling the nested SELECT statement once for every chain? So it works but not feasible for my full dataset unfortunately. But I have an idea involving a separate Left Join to find the chains that should return Null values, and then UNIONing them to the chains that do return values. Will post it up if I can get it working.