# MS Access: Error from WHERE condition evaluated on query inside join

Tags: sql, ms-access

When I paste the following query into SQL View in Access 2007:

```
SELECT ID_Entry, DateVal
FROM (SELECT [Query A].ID_Entry, DateVal
     FROM [Query A] INNER JOIN [Query B] 
     ON [Query A].ID_Entry = [Query B].ID_Entry
     )  AS QueryAJoinB
ORDER BY ID_Entry, DateVal;
```

it returns a large recordset whose smallest value of `ID_Entry` is 19. I need to select records from that recordset based on the value of the field `DateVal`. (`ID_Entry` is a table index. `DateVal` is calculated as `CDate(CleanRegData(<arguments with data from the current record>))`. The function `CleanRegData()` is defined in VBA.) When I put a WHERE condition on `DateVal`, as such:

```
SELECT ID_Entry, DateVal
FROM (SELECT [Query A].ID_Entry, DateVal
     FROM [Query A] INNER JOIN [Query B] 
     ON [Query A].ID_Entry = [Query B].ID_Entry
     )  AS QueryAJoinB
WHERE DateVal = Date()
ORDER BY ID_Entry, DateVal;
```

the query crashes with an error on `CleanRegData()`. Debugging indicates that the function is called with arguments from the record for `ID_Entry = 1`. The error is correct because that record does not contain the data needed by `CleanRegData()`. That is the reason for using the above query -- to select the records for which `DateVal` can be evaluated before trying to evaluate it.

The recordset returned by `Query A` has values of `ID_Entry` that start with 19, but the recordset of `Query B` has all values of `ID_Entry`, starting with 1. The join on those two queries is supposed to reduce the recordset to only those records returned by `Query A` -- which are the records for which `DateVal` can be evaluated.

But it appears that putting the WHERE condition on field `DateVal` causes it to be evaluated for records in `Query B`, where the definition of that field is not valid. How do I get the WHERE condition to be executed only on the recordset of the join, and not on the queries inside the join?

Here is a picture of the second query above running in Design View:

[image]

Clicking on "Debug" takes me to `CleanRegData()` with its argument values obtained from the record for `ID_Entry = 1`, which does not have the data needed by `CleanRegData()`, which is why the query crashed. But if I delete the condition on `DateVal`, the query returns a recordset in the which the lowest value of `ID_Entry` is 19. So my question is, how is Access finding the data from that record for `ID_Entry = 1`? That record should not be available in this query. Or what am I not understanding that is making this happen?

Comment: SQL products are free to re-arrange predicates in queries as part of optimization, provided they don't affect the results of the query. Unfortunately, Microsoft's SQL products (Access and SQL Server) always seem to forget that proviso and will sometimes generate errors due to this re-arrangement that would not have happened had no re-arrangement taken place. (I don't know if other companies products also do this, just aware of it with MS)

Comment: Of course, the bigger question to ask here is why you've got a table containing a column called `DateVal` that isn't of `Date/Time` data type and in fact is storing values that cannot even be converted into dates.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever - I've edited the post to explain what `DateVal` is (not a field in a table). Re your first comment, there is only one predicate in this query, so nothing to rearrange. Surely, you're not suggesting that Access is mixing the `WHERE` clause in this query with the `ON` clause inside the subquery, are you? What is the point of a subquery if it is not evaluated before applying the operations of the outer query to it?

Comment: Yes, that's what can happen. In SQL Server, a related issue is [logged here](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/537419/sql-server-should-not-raise-illogical-errors). There is a logical processing order that should be followed, or if the system uses a different processing order, it should produce results "as if" it had followed the logical processing order. Both SQL Server and Access fall down here, by generating errors because they're not following the logical processing order. I'm not aware of an Access bug tracker like Connect so cannot tell you of specific Access errs.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever - Wow, amazing. I've been using Access for many years for some big and complex projects and didn't know it was capable of flaking like this. It's scary because a bug like this could cause wrong results without any indication of error. Seems strange that there isn't more written about this than that link you sent. Also, much of the discussion there seems to assume the problem is in the conversion, rather than the logical order. I don't see how to apply any of those workarounds to my case. Not sure what to do except saving mid results to temp table, which is clugey.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever - In case you were not notified when I posted my answer, I'm entering this comment so you will be notified. Thanks for helping lead me to the answer.

Comment: What do you mean, "DateVal is calculated as CDate(CleanRegData(<arguments with data from the current record>))." What is the expression in your query? Is it a kind of SQL calculated field? Is it a formula in a cell? How has it come to be? (I realize Access documentation is poor so there may be no easy officially documented way to describe it.)

Comment: @philipxy - Coming back to this project a year later! The project works with a database I did not create that contains a lot of messed up text. CleanRegData(), which is defined in VBA, takes arguments consisting of segments of that text and follows an algorithm to clean them up and return meaningful data. That's why I didn't specify its arguments -- they would be meaningless to anyone not familiar with the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I would like to thank “Damien_The_Unbeliever”, who guided me, via his comments on my question, to understanding the source of the problem. As usual, once you understand the problem, the solution is at hand. I don’t know why he posted his remarks as comments instead of as an answer. Had he posted them as an answer, I’d have accepted it, but since he didn't I’m posting my own answer here so people can know the solution to the problem. I see that he already has a reputation of over 100k, so presumably he’s not concerned about the answer points.

Summarizing Damien’s comments, the problem was that Access was incorrectly and amazingly mixing the query's WHERE predicate with the join condition in the ON clause of the subquery! This caused it to attempt to evaluate `DateVal` on records for which that field is not defined, and thereby crash the query.

Here are references on this problem, the first provided by Damien, the others found with some research once I knew what to look for:

- Discussion of a similar problem on *Microsoft Connect*: [*SQL Server should not raise illogical errors*](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/537419/sql-server-should-not-raise-illogical-errors)
- Outer join analog of this problem documented by Allen Browne: [*Bug: Outer join expressions retrieved wrongly*](http://allenbrowne.com/BugOuterJoinExpression.html)
- Microsoft documentation of a problem that might be related (I haven't checked to see if it's really the same problem): [*ACC2000: Outer Join with WHERE Clause Returns Unexpected Records*](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/208880)
- StackOverflow discussion of the outer join analog of the problem: [*Access 2007 - Left Join to a query returns #Error instead of Null*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17170426/access-2007-left-join-to-a-query-returns-error-instead-of-null)

In the fourth reference, the answer by “CWeb” gave me the clue to how to develop a workaround. What I had to do was put the WHERE predicate inside an iif() that tests the join condition again, which prevents `DateVal` from being evaluated on the wrong records. It’s a bit clugey, as workarounds always are, but it works. When I do that, I no longer need the subquery QueryAJoinB, whose purpose was to get the join to happen before the WHERE is evaluated, which wasn’t happening (which was the problem). Here is the query that works now:

```
SELECT ID_Entry, DateVal
FROM [Query A] INNER JOIN [Query B] ON [Query A].ID_Entry = [Query B].ID_Entry
WHERE IIf([Query A].[ID_Entry] = [Query B].[ID_Entry], [DateVal] = Date(), False)
ORDER BY ID_Entry, DateVal;
```

Success is sweet! Thanks again, Damien.