# Invalid use of Null in basic JOIN query

Tags: sql, ms-access, null

I am trying to run the following query in Access:

```
SELECT CompareByOrderAndDescr.BOrder
FROM CompareByOrderAndDescr
LEFT JOIN OrdersNotReceived ON CompareByOrderAndDescr.BOrder = OrdersNotReceived.BOrder
WHERE OrdersNotReceived.BOrder Is Null
```

However, I am getting the "Invalid use of Null" error message.

I have two saved queries called "CompareByOrderAndDescr" and "OrdersNotReceived".  There are no Null values in either query's "BOrder" field.  I have been searching for causes of the error, but none of them seem to apply here.

I thought this was basic SQL for finding records from one table that are not in another table.  What am I missing?

Edit: Just to clarify, both of the following queries return 0 rows:

```
SELECT * FROM CompareByOrderAndDescr
WHERE BOrder IS NULL
```

and

```
SELECT * FROM OrdersNotReceived
WHERE BOrder IS NULL
```

Also, for what it's worth, here's the original query I began with before saving the OrdersNotReceived query as its own thing in an attempt to break the problem down into smaller pieces:

```
SELECT BOrder
FROM CompareByOrderAndDescr cb
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT BOrder
    FROM CompareByOrderAndDescr
    WHERE [Received]='Not Received') nr ON nr.BOrder=cb.BOrder
```

Comment: If you are looking for records where the join field is null in the table on the right side of the join, functionally this is the same as an inner join with no where clause

Comment: @DavidCram what?, no, it's not the same as an `INNER JOIN`

Comment: @DavidCram Thanks- However, I just tried it as an INNER JOIN and received the same error about invalid use of Null, unfortunately

Comment: I always forget Access's little quirks but that looks right to me. Maybe you need to say `isnull(OrdersNotReceived.BOrder) = true`

Comment: With regard to your edit, the NULL would appear after the LEFT JOIN if there were records in the first table not in the second

Comment: *Scratch... Scratch...* Yeah, I understand what you're trying to do here, and I honestly can't see why it isn't working. It seems doubtful that Access's query-planner would have *screwed up* (especially on such a trivial query), but I've seen it do screwy things before.

Comment: If `OrdersNotReceived` uses any sort of functions, you may be running into this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17170426/access-2007-left-join-to-a-query-returns-error-instead-of-null -- but from your original query it doesn't look like that.

Answer (score 0):

Please check if CompareByOrderAndDescr.BOrder and OrdersNotReceived.BOrder columns both allow null values or not?

Comment: See edit to question, there are no nulls in the columns